# Listview selection highlighted wrong

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view, in that list view I need to get the selected item position by clicking on image on the list item(I am showing image color change when clicked on that image).I am getting position of list item by clicking on image but, once click on image I got the two more color change images on other list items. I am unable findout why it is happening my list size is 13 items. It showing  for one click every 5 items image color highlighted. here I am using toggle button with drawable to change image color. please help me.

here is my code
this is the toggle image on the list item

```
<ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/tick_mark"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textOff=""
                    android:textOn=""


                    android:background="@drawable/selected"
                    android:layout_width="30sp"
                    android:layout_height="30sp"
                    />
```

this is my adapter class

```
public class Choose_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
ArrayList<Choose_pojo>data;
Activity activity;
LayoutInflater inflater;

LinearLayout more_btn;
public Choose_adapter(Activity context,ArrayList<Choose_pojo> items){
    this.data       =items;
    this.activity   =context;
    inflater        =(LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view=convertView;

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_diet_row,null);
    }


    final ToggleButton tick_mark =(ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.tick_mark);



    tick_mark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



           IngredientSession.addIndex1(position);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

here is my activity class

```
public class Choose_activity extends Activity{

Choose_adapter adapter;
ListView lv;
ArrayList<Choose_pojo> list1= Choose_pojo.feedData();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.choose_diet_list);

     lv =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.diet_list);
    loadInitials();
}

private void loadInitials() {
    adapter=new Choose_adapter(this,list1);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

here I am using pojo class Choose_pojo with static method

```
public class Choose_diet_pojo {
String item_name;
double energy_weight;
double fat_weight;
double fiber_wieght;
double protien_weight;
double Ca_wt;
double AvP_wt;
double Sodium_wt;
double Methionine_wt;
double Lysine;
String title;
String mintitle;

public double getEnergy_weight() {
    return energy_weight;
}

public void setEnergy_weight(double energy_weight) {
    this.energy_weight = energy_weight;
}

public double getFat_weight() {
    return fat_weight;
}

public void setFat_weight(double fat_weight) {
    this.fat_weight = fat_weight;
}

public double getFiber_wieght() {
    return fiber_wieght;
}

public void setFiber_wieght(double fiber_wieght) {
    this.fiber_wieght = fiber_wieght;
}

public double getProtien_weight() {
    return protien_weight;
}

public void setProtien_weight(double protien_weight) {
    this.protien_weight = protien_weight;
}

public double getCa_wt() {
    return Ca_wt;
}

public void setCa_wt(double ca_wt) {
    Ca_wt = ca_wt;
}

public double getAvP_wt() {
    return AvP_wt;
}

public void setAvP_wt(double avP_wt) {
    AvP_wt = avP_wt;
}

public double getSodium_wt() {
    return Sodium_wt;
}

public void setSodium_wt(double sodium_wt) {
    Sodium_wt = sodium_wt;
}

public double getMethionine_wt() {
    return Methionine_wt;
}

public void setMethionine_wt(double methionine_wt) {
    Methionine_wt = methionine_wt;
}

public double getLysine() {
    return Lysine;
}

public void setLysine(double lysine) {
    Lysine = lysine;
}

public String getMintitle() {
    return mintitle;
}

public void setMintitle(String mintitle) {
    this.mintitle = mintitle;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getItem_name() {
    return item_name;
}

public void setItem_name(String item_name) {
    this.item_name = item_name;
}

public static ArrayList<Choose_pojo> feedData() {
    ArrayList<Choose_pojo> list = new ArrayList<Choose_pojo>();

    Choose_pojo data1 = new Choose_pojo();
    data1.setTitle("abc");
   data1.setMintitle("ab");
    data1.setEnergy_weight(3373);
    data1.setFat_weight(3.5);
    data1.setFiber_wieght(1.9);
    data1.setProtien_weight(7.5);
    data1.setAvP_wt(0.12);
    data1.setCa_wt(0.01);
    data1.setLysine(0.24);
    data1.setMethionine_wt(0.18);
    data1.setSodium_wt(0.02);

    list.add(data1);


    Choose_pojo data2 = new Choose_pojo();
    data2.setTitle("pqr");
    data2.setMintitle("pq");
    data2.setEnergy_weight(1300);
    data2.setFat_weight(4.0);
    data2.setFiber_wieght(10);
    data2.setProtien_weight(14.8);
    data2.setAvP_wt(0.38);
    data2.setCa_wt(0.14);
    data2.setLysine(0.6);
    data2.setMethionine_wt(0.2);
    data2.setSodium_wt(0.06);
    list.add(data2);
    return list;
}

}
```

In above data1,data2 like I have upto data13

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: I posted code please see once